# Server Side Datatables using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, datatables

I'll shorten my PHP that fetches from the server. I'm using the SSP helper class file :

```
//rest of code up here
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where, "business_name != 'xyzcompany'") 
);
```

This works fine.

However, I'd like to replace 'xyzcompany' dynamically based on a user input. For security, I'd like to use PDO. I know how to use PDO in general, but now how I'd fold it into this datatables example. I have read that the SSP helper handles PDO, I just can't find documentation for how to use it. For example pseudo-code:

```
//rest of code up here
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
$business_name = $_POST['biz']; //supplied by user in text input
:biz_name = $business_name; //I know this isn't correct syntax
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where, "business_name != :biz_name") 
);
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php) is the class he is referring to, its from DataTables, but reading the code I don't want to make heads or tails out of it. Who would have though PDO could be this complex..

Comment: Where does PDO come into play here? All I see is something that emits JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
# Obtain an PHP PDO connection from a connection details array
$db = SSP::db($sql_details);

echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where, "business_name != ".$db->quote($business_name)) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. If I wanted to add more parameters (like business_name !=x AND city=y), is there a way to do this? I can't find any documentation on how to structure these "SSP::complex" queries.

Comment: @jonmrich, you can add more parameters the same way, i.e. `"(business_name != ".$db->quote($business_name)." AND city = ".$db->quote($city).")"`. Note that adding parentheses would help if you have complex logic.